# Puppet templates, defined types, and variable scope

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to get my head wrapped around why this happening. The following code will not write the variable $group, but it will write the array $users in the template.

```
define bar::foo(
  String $group = $title,
  Array $users
) {

  file {'/tmp/my.file':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('bar/test.epp'),
  }
}
```

using an epp template that looks like this:

```
group: <%= $group %>
users: [<%= $users.map |$x|{ "'${x}'"}.join(', ') %>]
```

If I pass though the variable to the template, then $group gets written to 'my.file'.

```
define bar::foo(
  String $group = $title,
  Array $users
) {

  file {'/tmp/my.file':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('bar/test.epp', { group => $group }),
  }
}
```

How can the variable $users be present in the template's scope, while $group is not in the first example?

Comment: I feel like something is absent from this example that would explain this behavior, but also it is worth noting there are reasons why the vast majority have stuck with `.erb` over `.epp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using epp and would like to get the $groups variable then you have to write the full scope of the variable $::bar::foo::groups inside your template.